# Gangster and M1SMG, what is the difference?

Tags: watch-dogs

I have Vigilante edition of Watch Dog, which include the Palace Pack, which give access to a thompson skinned, 4star assault rifle "M1SMG".

Now, after completing QRCodes missions, I unlocked the "Gangster", which is a 4starts assault rifle skinned as a smg...

I don t see any difference between the two of them, so the question is...

Is there any difference between the Pack Palace M1SMG and the Gangster? If so, what are they?

EDIT:

Okay, wiki say M1 SMG is classified as SMG while the Gangster is classified as Assault rifle, so if nothing else come up, the difference would only be the ammo used.

EDIT 2:

It does seems the weapons are the sames, can anybody confirm that the color are the sames too? (Wiki says the Gangster have a "gold tint" while the M1 SMG have "wood stock").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, from [what I found](http://watchdogs.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Submachine_Guns), they are both classified as *Submachine Gun*, both containing 50 bullets per round and designed after the *"Tommy Gun"*. They only difference I can spot is that they both have different ways of being unlocked and the color. Both have a 4 star rating and work similar in gunfights in my opinion!

**color confirmation**:
[M1 SMG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwYIpBbInus) vs. [Gangster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Jxn-VAp67Q)

Comment: I didn t knew Ubi was so cheap they'll put the same gun twice with different name : / Wiki says the Gangster have a "gold tint", anyone can confirm if the colour is different between the two?

Comment: Didn't think so either, but apparently it's exactly the case... sorry, mate! And I can confirm it. I edited the answer for you, check out the YouTube Links.

Answer (score 1):

The Gangster is gold with a black stock and M1 is grey with a wood stock.